# EF6 Code First throwing NullReferenceException when no PRIMARY KEY exists

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

This is a bit of a strange one. I do not have administrative access on the database and am working with a table that is properly constrained, but has no primary key defined.

The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    KeyColumn VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    BitValue BIT NOT NULL
)
```

Within EF, there's a model:

```
[Table("Foo")]
public partial class FooModel
{
    [Key] //Also tried by setting this in the ModelBinder as well with no luck
    public string KeyColumn {get;set;}
    public bool BitValue {get;set;}
}

//Within DbContext subclass:
public DbSet<FooModel> {get;set;}

//When in code:
context.FooModel throws NullReferenceException.
```

I believe this is because EF cannot map to the underlying table in spite of the identical schema. `KeyColumn` is a valid key, but is not defined as explicitly as the PRIMARY KEY.

Is there a way to force EF CodeFirst to map to this underlying table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this through using the leaky abstraction provided by EF6.

```
var m = context.FooModel.SqlQuery(@"
    SELECT KeyColumn
    ,   BitValue 
        FROM Foo 
        WHERE KeyColumn = @KeyColumn
    ", new SqlParameter("@KeyColumn", keyColumnValue)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Other operations, such as adding and saving models seemed to work after this.